# php-fpm so many memcache connections for sessions

Tags: php, session, memcached

We are using memcache with php-fpm to store sessions.

Most of our website requests are api requests where sessions are not using and not staring `session_start()` in application.

Memcache server load is very due to more number of connections, even no `session_start()` in application.

Is php-fpm make connection to memcache on every request even no sessions are used?

How to disable make connection memcache if no session start in app?

using below configuration in my www.conf in php-fpm

`php_value[session.save_handler] = memcache
php_value[session.save_path] = "tcp://session.amazonaws.com:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"`

Comment: Hi you need to post you sample code. session_start() is to start session in php. but in the request page if you try to connect memcached it will create a connection instance automatically.

Comment: Hi @Vigikaran we not using session_start() in php even then php-fpm is creating connection to memcached. I don't want to make connection to memcached if i didn't start the session.

Comment: Post your code would be easy for everyone to solve the problem